# check if row contains characters

Tags: shell, regular-expression

I have file that looks like

```
This row contains characters

this row to

*-=?§/

this             is the lat row of the file
```

How can I only print only rows that contains some characters -- aka all but empty rows?

I have tried

```
cat file | grep '[a-zA-Z0-9,\.,?{}()]'
```

but it didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
grep -v '^$' file.txt
```

this will print the rows that are not empty.

If you have only space or tab in the line and want to ignore those lines too:

```
grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*$'
```

Comment: this prints one row that is empty

Comment: @trolkura no...note the `-v` option, `-v` will reverse the match..

Comment: indeed i know about -v ibut somehow it still first empty row (first row in file isnt empty) // edit  it prints it bcs there is a space .. how can i filter spacebar / tabulator out?

Comment: @trolkura check my edits

Comment: Also, `grep '[[:print:]]' file` -- that is, at least one "printable" character. This will also filter out lines with a control character, which `grep -v '[[:blank:]]'` will not

Comment: No, belay that. Should be `grep '[[:graph:]]'`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$ grep '[[:graph:]]' file
```

to get all lines that has an sort of visible character in `file`.

Alternatively,

```
$ grep -v '^[^[:graph:]]*$' file
```

to filter out all the lines that only have non-visible characters on them.

Answer (score 0):

try with awk command.

```
awk 'NF>0' file

awk 'NF==0' file
```